# Unity Build Problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I have a small problem. I have created a project in Unity.

See picture:

[image: screen1]

The scene in Unity shows everything as it should. But when I build it only a part is visible.

See picture:

[image: screen2]

What am I doing fundamentally wrong and how can I fix my error?

- OS: Windows
- Unity Version: 2020.3.30f1

Comment: I don't know much of unity, but is it correct to assume that this is a camera/zoom position problem ?

Comment: @PaulKaram You can display a "preview" in the Unity Editor. Everything is fine there. The problem only arises during the build process. At least that's what I assume.

Comment: And what size screen is your preview window set to? How does that compare to the runtime resolution

Comment: @BugFinder The compiled version is 2.7x larger than the "preview" version. So it looks like 2.7x has been scrolled in.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the camera left and check the game tab.